# Call a C++ DLL from a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, interop

I'm currently trying to integrate a C++ DLL into our C# application, but I'm not able to identify what's the correct way to call one of their methods. In two different places of the documentation the method definition are not equal:

```
ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(unsigned char *ptrCodeline,int* iLength) 

ImageAndScanError WINAPI GetMicrInfo(char* cMicrInfo,int* iInfoLength);

/*
ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(unsigned char *ptrCodeline,int* iLength) 

Parameters: 

ptrCodeline: a pointer to the output buffer that will receive the code line read by the MICR algorithm. The ptrCodeline should allocate room for 96 characters. 

iLength: the number of characters contained in the code line 

Function: Read MICR line on the check. This function must be called after StartScan . 

Returns: ErrorNone is returned upon success. Otherwise, an enum ImageAndScanError value that indicates the reason for failure is returned. 
*/
```

This is how I'm including the dll method

```
[DllImport("ScanDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
```

And this are all the combinations that I've made so far

```
public static extern ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(out IntPtr cMicrInfo, out int iInfoLength);
public static extern ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(out byte[] cMicrInfo, out int iInfoLength);
public static extern ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(out string cMicrInfo, out int iInfoLength);
public static extern ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(out StringBuilder cMicrInfo, out int iInfoLength);

IntPtr cMicrInfoTMP;
byte[] cMicrInfoTMP= new byte[96];
string cMicrInfoTMP;
StringBuilder cMicrInfoTMP;

GetMicrInfo(out cMicrInfoTMP, out iInfoLengthTMP);
```

When I use IntPtr, the value that the debug gives me in VS2010 is 859256727 with a size of 4, and when I do

```
string myString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(cMicrInfoTMP);
```

I always get an empty string.

When I try any of the others (byte[], string, StringBuilder) I get

```
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at
0x53e6716a, on thread 0x1084. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may
be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user
code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop
or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allocate a buffer, then pass to the native function.

```
//error handling omitted
[DllImport("your.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(IntPtr ptrCodeline,ref int bytesCopied);

IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bufferLen);
Win32API.ZeroMemory(ip, (uint)(bufferLen));
int bytesCopied=0;
GetMicrInfo(ip, ref bytesCopied);
string info= Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(bytesCopied);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ip);
```

If you do not need to reuse the buffer during multiple calls of GetMicrInfo, you can use the default marshaler for StringBuilder:

```
[DllImport("your.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(StringBuilder ptrCodeline,ref int bytesCopied);
StringBuilder ptrCodeline(bufferLen);
int bytesCopied=0;
GetMicrInfo(ptrCodeline, ref bytesCopied);
```

It comes with a performance hit if you call GetMicrInfo multiple times, because on each call the default CLR marshaller creates a marshalling buffer for pinning and for unicode-ANSI conversion. This hit may be negligible if the function isn't being called frequently or does not return a lot of data.

Reference:

- [Default Marshaling for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx)
- [Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx#S4)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, `out` parameters are used when the callee creates the object. You need to provide an existing buffer to the function so you should initialize the StringBuilder first. The marshaller then passes a pointer to object's the internal character buffer to the function.

You do have to figure out which character set and encoding is being used for the MICR string. It could be UTF-16, in which case, change the declaration to `CharSet.Unicode`.

Try this:

```
[DllImport("ScanDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern ImageAndScanError GetMicrInfo(StringBuilder cMicrInfo, out int iInfoLength);

public String GetMicrInfo()
{
    StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder(96);
    int length;
    ImageAndScanError error = GetMicrInfo(info, out length);
    if (error != ImageAndScanError.ErrorNone) throw new Exception(String.Format("GetMicrInfo error: {0}", error));
    return info.ToString();
}
```